# UK NARIC Statement of Comparability for Spouse Job Seekers

Tags: united-kingdom, education, employment, qualifications

The UK NARIC site states...

> The UK NARIC Statement of Comparability is an officially recognised
>   document that confirms the recognition of an overseas qualification
>   and its comparable level in the UK, irrespective of it being an
>   academic, vocational or professional award. It is used by
>   universities, colleges, employers and Government departments and
>   agencies forming part of their decision-making process. A Statement of
>   Comparability can be used to help support applications made under
>   Tiers 1 and 2 of the Points Based System for immigration to the UK;
>   particularly the Graduate Entrepreneur route within Tier 1.

Source:  [NARIC Statement of Comparability](http://www.naric.org.uk/naric/individuals/Compare%20Qualifications/Statement%20of%20Comparability.aspx)

While the UK scuttled most of the Tier 1 route some time ago and the other tiered routes are evolved beyond recognition, a NARIC Statement of Comparability can be used to meet the English speaking requirement for all migrants, including spouses.

It costs GBP 55 and takes about 6 weeks.  The product is a letter like [this sample](http://www.naric.org.uk/naric/individuals/Compare%20Qualifications/documents/SoC.pdf).  I am already aware that NARIC does not enjoy an esteemed position by some expats who have used them in the Tiered routes.

A spouse does not require a work permit and does not need to show the Home Office anything from NARIC. The question concerns UK employers and the standards they would use.

For those incoming migrant spouses who wish to seek professional employment, is getting such a Statement of Comparability to show prospective employers an advisable preparatory step?  Is it a good thing to 'have on hand'? Or do contemporary HR departments have sufficient information at their fingertips with Google?

Comment: My hunch, and it's only a hunch, is that if there are any questions about English language proficiency, it's worth getting a well known qualification / certification / level. I'm not sure that NARIC is commonly known

Comment: I am currently waiting for the Statement of Comparability to arrive and stumbled upon this question. Did you go ahead with NARIC at all? How did that go?

Comment: Best to answer the question and I can reply to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NARIC is an independent organization with which the UK Government contracts on an open public tender basis for an external supplier to deliver the NARIC service (no affiliation). As with any such fee-based service outsourced by a government, it is elective, one of the options available.

For those who wish to have their current qualifications evaluated, rather than, separately, sitting and passing a test, [NARIC evaluation](http://ecctis.co.uk/naric/individuals/compare%20qualifications/Statement%20of%20Comparability.aspx) may be expeditious.

> **Knowledge of English**
>   You may need to prove your knowledge of the English language when you apply.
>
> You can prove your knowledge of English by either:
>   <
>   passing an [approved English language test](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/guidance-on-applying-for-uk-visa-approved-english-language-tests) with at least CEFR level B1 in reading, writing, speaking and listening
>   having an academic qualification that was taught in English and is recognised by [UK NARIC](http://www.naric.org.uk/visasandnationality) as being equivalent to a UK bachelor’s degree, master’s degree or PhD
>
> You may be able to meet the English language requirement in other ways or need a higher level of English in some circumstances. Check the [full visa guidance](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/guidance-on-application-for-uk-visa-as-tier-2-worker) for detailed information.

NARIC’s recognition, acceptance, and repute stray into reasons-to-close (opinion based, too broad). Some may wish to have their qualifications compared, and may feel that such a comparison assists opportunities post-immigration. Beyond using its services for the English sufficiency standard, visa applicants are not obliged to have it assess of their educational or employment credentials.